# laravel with relationship callback function and join it

Tags: php, laravel

It's hard to explain what I need, but I will try.

```
$this->order->where("client_id", 5)
    ->with([
        "roadOrderStatus" => function ($query) {
            $query->select("id", "identifier");
        },
        "currency"        => function ($query) {
            $query->join("translations", "currencies", '=', 'translations.id')
                ->join('translation_entries', 'translations.id', '=', 'translation_entries.translation_id')
                ->join('languages', 'translation_entries.language_id', '=', 'languages.id')
                ->whereIn('languages.code', ["eng"]);
        },
    ])->get();
```

I have two relationships on order (roadOrderStatus and currency). if in callbacks, I don't write anything, response is great. it works. but currency needs translation, because (currencies table has column called name and it's integer, because it gets translated). so if you look at my code, when fetching currency relationship , i also need to join to translations to get translated currency, but if I write joins in currency relationship callback like above, it returns - `currency - null`

I tried -

```
1) ->whereIn('languages.code', ["eng"])->get();

2) return $query->join("translations", .e.t.c)
```

My order model--

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models\Orders;
use App\Http\Traits\ScopeTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RoadOrder extends Model
{
    use ScopeTrait;

    public function orderFinancialProperty(){
        return $this->morphOne("App\Http\Models\Orders\OrderFinancialProperty", "orderFinancialPropertable");
    }

    public function roadOrderStatus(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Http\Models\Orders\RoadOrderStatus");
    }
    public function roadTransportType(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Http\Models\Transport_Type\RoadTransportType");
    }

    public function currency(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Statics\Currency');
    }

    public function insurancer(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Http\Models\Insurance\Insurancer");
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use eloquent relationships? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships 
could you also provide a clearer picture of the relationships in place?

Comment: this is eloquent relationships belongsTo (one to many)

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `Order` model.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili okey, do you have the relationship set in the model or just in the database? you can do pretty easy quering with relations https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: I updated the code and include order model code.

Comment: Have you tried to provide the selected fields in your currency query ?

Comment: yeah, select works, but as soon as I write join, it returns null.

Comment: what if you don't use join and act like the hop from order to currency is over a pivot table? then you wouldn't need the joins and could use eloquent?